# how to assign two integral (romberg subroutine) inside loops in fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm trying to write a code for this formula

[image: (Dh)*(integral( (integral(dz/E(z)) / E(z)) dz)]

if I use romberg for each part, the result will be wrong (I'm checking the results with cosmology calculator)

```
zmin=0
zm=0.44 (any redshift in catalog)
zzm=0.5 (highest limit for each bin)

call Romberg (dis,dDistCa,zmin,zm)
call Romberg (dix,dDistCa,zmin,zzm)

Vnew=abs(((dix*(c/h0))**3.)-((dix*(c/h0))**3.))*s
```

so I wrote it in this way :

```
do jm=zmin,zm,zstep          
     zjm=jm+zstep        
     call Romberg (dis,dDistCa,zbN,zjm)     
     fF=fF+((c/h0)**3.)*(dis**2.)*((omegam*(1+jm)**3+omegal)**(-0.5))*zstep                                      
end do

do jm=zmin,zzm,zstep
     zjm=jm+zstep
     call Romberg (dis,dDistCa,zbN,zjm)
     fF1=fF1+((c/h0)**3.)*(dis**2.)*((omegam*(1+jm)**3+omegal)**(-0.5))*zstep           
end do  
v=(ff-ff2)*s
```

it gives the right answer,so I have to choose the zsteps very small `0.00001` to have precise output ,but it has an other problem , inside the other loops it takes at least one day to run in larger numbers like `zzm=3.2`

I would be thankful if you help me I can modify it.

Comment: From where is the "Romberg" subroutine taken?

Comment: numerical recipes fortran 90 ,,,,,,, but I don't think the problem is related to Romberg -  second integral is inside the first one, playing rule as function , problem is in loops I don't know how I can write it to run in the shortest time

Comment: seems like in first approach there is TYPO, dix is used 2 times instead of dis

Comment: no it's just a dummy parameter , I have checked the results , answers are correct in do loop parts problem is in steps, imagine zmin starts from 0 and it increases up to 3, zstep is 0.00001 so loop should be run 3000 times and it's two loop inside other loops, ---- romberg can calculate integral directly and " ff " is basic defination of integral , these two loops are not professional , I need to find best way to calculate these integrals in the shortest time

Comment: define a function that calls rhomberg for the inner integral and pass that function to rhomberg for the outer integral.

Comment: neither of your examples seems to relate to that expression by the way.  showing the integration limits might help.

Comment: If you care about numerical accuracy, why aren't you using double precision numerical constants? For example zm=0.44d0 instead of zm=0.44. Are your variables declared as double precision or something like real(kind=8)?

Comment: Your formula doesn't really make sense... If you evaluate the inner integral (with fixed limits), it will be a constant and can be pulled out of the outer integral. Then the outer integral is the same as the inner integral... You should be more precise with the variable names and dependencies in the functions.

Comment: this a comoving volume formula in cosmology and " E(z)=(omegam*(1+z)^3 + omegal)^(-0.5)" and yes all my variables are double precision, the limits of integrals are (zmin=0. , zmax= 3.5). in the first example I supposed that the inner integral should be constant multiply to the outer integral but result is not correct(I have checked it with cosmology calculator ) only with the second example I could have the right answer, but logically it's not right and it takes days to run (3.5*1000 times this loop will run) I guess there should be special routines or better idea that I couldn't find out

Comment: well, looking up comoving volume i cant find anything remotely like what you have here. you should seek out some cosmology forum